# How Do I Evaluate A User-Defined Expression 44100 Times Per Second

Tags: c++, signal-processing

I am working on a VST plugin using C++. The plugin will allow the user to enter a math expression, which will then be run 44100 times per second in order to generate sound. I am new to realtime stuff like this, as well as interpreting user entered expressions.

The issue is that I cannot find a method to evaluate a user defined function that can run that fast. My best attempt has been to convert the user entered expression into RPN when it's entered, and then having a function evaluate the RPN expression to generate the audio. I implemented the RPN evaluation function and hard-coded an RPN expression to test it. While it seems to evaluate correctly, it does not seem to be doing it fast enough.

Here is my evaluation function, in addition to a couple RPN expressions:

```
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <deque>


/*
 * an RPN expression is stored as a deque of strings
 * 
 * each string is either an operator, a number, or the single variable t
 * 
 * the deque is read from front to back
*/

std::deque<std::string> simpleCase, complexCase;

//simple expression, just the variable t
simpleCase.push_back("t");

//more complex expression, t*(42&(t>>11))
complexCase.push_back("t");
complexCase.push_back("42");
complexCase.push_back("t");
complexCase.push_back("11");
complexCase.push_back(">>");
complexCase.push_back("&");
complexCase.push_back("*");

/*
 * The evalRPN function takes an RPN deque, plugs in a supplied t,
 * and evaluates it.
 * 
 * The idea is that t increases continually, and that the integer overflow
 * causes the output to oscillate between 0 and 255.
 * 
 * t is a double, but I convert it to a uint32_t.
 * 
 * Allowed operators: bitwise logic (&, |, ^), bitshifts (<<, >>),
 * and math (+, -, *, /, %)
 * 
 * Allowed vars: t
 * 
 * Supplied numbers are converted from string to char arrays then to an int
 * 
 * This also assumes the RPN is not ill-formatted.
*/
uint8_t evalRPN(std::deque<std::string> rpnExpr, double tVal)
{
    std::stack<uint8_t> numberStack;
    std::string token;

    while(rpnExpr.size() > 0)
    {

        token = rpnExpr.front();
        rpnExpr.pop_front();

        if(token.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos)
        {
            //if token is a number
            numberStack.push((uint8_t)atoi(token.c_str()));
        }
        else if (token == "t")
        {
            numberStack.push((uint8_t)tVal);
        }
        else
        {
            uint8_t last = numberStack.top();
            numberStack.pop();
            uint8_t first = numberStack.top();
            numberStack.pop();

            if(token == "^")
            {
                numberStack.push(first ^ last);
            }
            else if (token == "&")
            {
                numberStack.push(first & last);
            }
            else if (token == "|")
            {
                numberStack.push(first | last);
            }
            else if (token == "<<")
            {
                numberStack.push(first >> last);
            }
            else if (token == ">>")
            {
                numberStack.push(first >> last);
            }
            else if (token == "+")
            {
                numberStack.push(first + last);
            }
            else if (token == "-")
            {
                numberStack.push(first - last);
            }
            else if (token == "*")
            {
                numberStack.push(first * last);
            }
            else if (token == "/")
            {
                numberStack.push(first / last);
            }
            else if (token == "%")
            {
                numberStack.push(first % last);
            }
        }
    }

    //assume one left in numberStack
    return(numberStack.top());
}
```

Are there any optimizations I can make in my RPN processing to make it potentially run fast enough? Alternatively is there another way of handling the RPN computation that's more efficient?

Additionally, is there another method that's C++ compatible for taking a user entered string representing a standard math expression, and then running that expression fast enough to be completed in under 1/44100th of a second?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, but maybe that'll help: Why are you calculating the same expression over and over again (44100 times to be exact). Why not store the result and execute it once?

Comment: JIT-ing it is an option.  LLVM could likely help you out here to some degree.  Granted, it is some extra work, as it eventually turns your interpreter into a compiler, and then you have to worry about the rest, but the performance would be better.  I don't know anything about VST or sound, though.  Interpreting rather than JITing is definitely going to slow you down, though.

Comment: If you don't want to JIT, you should definitely break down your RPN expression into some sort of AST or something like it, so you aren't doing string comparisons tens of thousands of times a second.

Comment: Don't go real time unless you have to. Generate the audio, buffer it, and then play it back. Trying to make the sound as you play it will require a carefully selected OS. You won't be be able to get the timing you need out of, for example, Windows and off-the-shelf-Linux. The jitter will result in a music experience vastly different than what was ordered.

Comment: Next thought. You don't want to reparse the RPN on the fly. Take the user input and translate it into an instruction medium that you can process quickly.

Comment: If OP's algorithm can't even keep up with 44.1k executions/second, it definitely won't be able to buffer.  Another, simpler option is to take in the RPN as a lua chunk and run it through luajit.  Then you'll get a lot of the optimization and the JIT with a very simple API.

Comment: Performing real time audio calculations at a sample rate of 44.1k should be no problem. I'm guessing the problem you have is that your are re-parsing the RPN every sample.

Comment: Can you test performance of your application? When I tested your function on online compiler (and I assume that it's not fast) I get 15 and 8 times more power than I need for simple and complex sample. Check it yourself http://www.tutorialspoint.com/viewproject.php?URL=compile_cpp11_online.php&PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRFdFN0s3QXhMcjQ.

Comment: There are plenty of embeddable programming language interpreters (for Basic, Lua, Forth, Scheme, Tcl, etc.) that can interpret far more than 44100 arithmetic statements and function calls per second on many contemporary platforms (including mobile phones).  Benchmark to find one fast enough on your target CPU and embed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.

Compiling your expression into RPN is a good start, and in fact it kinda looks to me like your code should probably be able to execute more than 88K expressions per second, unless they are quite long.

BUT, you can certainly do a lot better without too much trouble.

I would make an interface like this:

```
class Expression
{
    public:
    virtual uint32_t eval(uint32_t tVal) = 0;
};
```

You will then compile your expression into an implementation of this interface.

You can have an implementation for constants:

```
class ConstExpression : public Expression
{
    private:
    uint32_t m_constVal;

    public:
    // ...

    uint32_t eval(uint32_t tVal)
    {
         return m_constVal;
    }
};
```

...an implementation for a reference to `t`

```
class RefExpression : public Expression
{
    public:
    // ...

    uint32_t eval(uint32_t tVal)
    {
         return m_tVal;
    }
};
```

... and implementations for the binary operators

```
class AddExpression : public Expression
{
    private:
    auto_ptr<Expression> m_left;
    auto_ptr<Expression> m_right;

    public:
    // ...

    uint32_t eval(uint32_t tVal)
    {
         return m_left->eval(tVal) + m_right->eval(tVal);
    }
};
```

... maybe you want to do some template magic to avoid having to hand code so many operator classes.

Anyway, after compiling your expression into an Expression, you can evaluate it simply like theExpression->eval(t), and all the code executes in a reasonably efficient manner with no parsing, string compares, stack manipulation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about realtime generating code, compile it and then use as binary library function? I'm sure it will work much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. If you are building a vst, you have to use the vst libraries. The host daw will call the update functions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your advice! I have since implemented a solution I am immensely happy with. While none of the answers here directly informed me of this approach, they did inspire me.

I decided to parse the user-input infix expressions into polish notation (prefix), and then into binary trees. I implemented a TreeNode struct specifically for this, which is essentially a doubly linked list, but with 2 children instead of 1. Each TreeNode can either be set as a variable, a fixed number, or an operator. If it's set as an operator, it's opFunc function pointer member is set to a predefined function that performs that operator.

Each node has an evaluate(tVal) member function. If it's a fixed number, this just returns that number. If it's a variable, it just returns tVal. If it's an operator, it returns opFunc(first->evaluate(tVal), last->evaluate(tVal)), which recursively calculates the two nodes beneath it, then performs the it's operator on them.

I also implemented an ExpressionTree class which manages the tree and parses user input into a tree. It has public members for destroying the tree recursively, building the tree from a user input string, and evaluating the tree (it just needs to evaluate the root node).

Because this uses function pointers in a simple recursive tree, it's astoundingly fast to evaluate an ExpressionTree, even when the formulas get very large. Essentially, I have moved more or less as much processing as possible away from when the function is being evaluated and to when the formula is entered.

Below is the code I wrote for the expression trees. Note that only very limited operators exist, however it is easy to add new binary operators by including them in the precedence map, adding a function for them, and including a switch in setOp. There is also only one variable allowed, which is all my application will use.

There is also no error checking implemented at the moment, so invalid operators, spaces, or mismatched parentheses will result in undefined behavior ATM.

Also note that the expressions are processed as uint32_t and turned into a uint8_t at the end, as that's what my application calls for. When I'm done with this project, I may generalize this as a library and publish it.

TreeExpressions.hpp:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct TreeNode {
private:
    bool isOp = false;
    bool isVar = false;
    uint32_t value = 0;
    uint32_t(*opFunc)(uint32_t, uint32_t) = NULL;

    static inline uint32_t xorOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a ^ b); };
    static inline uint32_t andOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a & b); };
    static inline uint32_t orOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a | b); };
    static inline uint32_t lshiftOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a << b); };
    static inline uint32_t rshiftOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a >> b); };
    static inline uint32_t addOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a + b); };
    static inline uint32_t subOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a - b); };
    static inline uint32_t multOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a * b); };
    static inline uint32_t divOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a / b); };
    static inline uint32_t modOp(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) { return(a % b); };
public:
    TreeNode *first = NULL;
    TreeNode *last = NULL;
    TreeNode *parent = NULL;
    uint32_t evaluate(uint32_t tVal);
    void setOp(std::string op);
    void setVal(uint32_t val);
    void setVar();
};

class ExpressionTree
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, int> precedence;
    TreeNode *treeRoot;
    TreeNode *insertNode(TreeNode *leaf);
    void destroyTree(TreeNode *leaf);
public:
    ExpressionTree();
    ~ExpressionTree();
    void destroyTree();
    bool build(std::string formulaStr);
    uint8_t evaluate(uint32_t tVal);
};
```

TreeExpressions.cpp:

```
#include "TreeExpressions.h"

void TreeNode::setOp(std::string op)
{
    isVar = false;
    isOp = true;


    if (op == "^")
    {
        opFunc = &xorOp;
    }
    else if (op == "&")
    {
        opFunc = &andOp;
    }
    else if (op == "|")
    {
        opFunc = &orOp;
    }
    else if (op == "<<")
    {
        opFunc = &lshiftOp;
    }
    else if (op == ">>")
    {
        opFunc = &rshiftOp;
    }
    else if (op == "+")
    {
        opFunc = &addOp;
    }
    else if (op == "-")
    {
        opFunc = &subOp;
    }
    else if (op == "*")
    {
        opFunc = &multOp;
    }
    else if (op == "/")
    {
        opFunc = &divOp;
    }
    else if (op == "%")
    {
        opFunc = &modOp;
    }

}

void TreeNode::setVal(uint32_t val)
{
    isVar = false;
    isOp = false;

    value = val;
}

void TreeNode::setVar()
{
    isVar = true;
    isOp = false;
}

uint32_t TreeNode::evaluate(uint32_t tVal)
{
    if (isOp)
    {
        //if it's an op
        return( opFunc( first->evaluate(tVal), last->evaluate(tVal) ) );
    }
    else if (isVar)
    {
        //if it's a var
        return(tVal);
    }
    else
    {
        //if it's a number
        return(value);
    }
}



ExpressionTree::ExpressionTree()
{
    treeRoot = NULL;

    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
    precedence["*"] = 5;
    precedence["/"] = 5;
    precedence["%"] = 5;
    precedence["+"] = 6;
    precedence["-"] = 6;
    precedence["<<"] = 7;
    precedence[">>"] = 7;
    precedence["&"] = 10;
    precedence["^"] = 11;
    precedence["|"] = 12;
}

ExpressionTree::~ExpressionTree()
{
    destroyTree();
}

void ExpressionTree::destroyTree(TreeNode *leaf)
{
    if (leaf != NULL)
    {
        destroyTree(leaf->first);
        destroyTree(leaf->last);
        delete leaf;
    }
}

TreeNode *ExpressionTree::insertNode(TreeNode *leaf)
{
    if (leaf->first == NULL)
    {
        leaf->first = new TreeNode;
        leaf->first->parent = leaf;
        return(leaf->first);
    }
    else
    {
        leaf->last = new TreeNode;
        leaf->last->parent = leaf;
        return(leaf->last);
    }
}

void ExpressionTree::destroyTree()
{
    destroyTree(treeRoot);
}

bool ExpressionTree::build(std::string formulaStr)
{
    std::string::iterator stringIterator;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator stringVectorIterator;

    std::vector<std::string> formulaTokens;
    std::vector<std::string> pnTokens;
    std::stack<std::string> stringStack;
    std::string currentNumString = "";
    std::string currentTokenString = "";
    std::stack<TreeNode> nodeStack;
    TreeNode *currentNode;
    std::string currToken;
    bool treeIsDone;

    //tokenization

    for (stringIterator = formulaStr.begin(); stringIterator != formulaStr.end(); stringIterator++)
    {
        std::string currCharString(1, *stringIterator);

        currentTokenString.push_back(*stringIterator);

        if ((precedence.find(currentTokenString) != precedence.end()) || (currentTokenString == "(") || (currentTokenString == ")"))
        {
            //if the current token string is found in the precedence list (or is a parentheses)
            if (currentNumString != "")
            {
                formulaTokens.push_back(currentNumString);
                currentNumString = "";
            }

            formulaTokens.push_back(currentTokenString);
            currentTokenString = "";
        }
        else if (std::all_of(currentTokenString.begin(), currentTokenString.end(), ::isdigit))
        {
            //if the current token string is all digits
            currentNumString.append(currentTokenString);
            currentTokenString = "";
        }
        else if (currentTokenString == "t")
        {
            //if the current token string is the t variable
            formulaTokens.push_back(currentTokenString);
            currentTokenString = "";
        }
    }

    //convert to polish notation

    std::reverse(formulaTokens.begin(), formulaTokens.end());

    stringStack.push(")");

    for (stringVectorIterator = formulaTokens.begin(); stringVectorIterator != formulaTokens.end(); stringVectorIterator++)
    {
        currToken = *stringVectorIterator;
        if ((precedence.find(currToken) == precedence.end()) && (currToken != "(") && (currToken != ")"))
        {
            pnTokens.push_back(currToken);
        }
        else if (currToken == ")")
        {
            stringStack.push(currToken);
        }
        else if (precedence.find(currToken) != precedence.end())
        {
            if (stringStack.size() > 0)
            {
                if (stringStack.top() != ")")
                {
                    while (precedence[stringStack.top()] <= precedence[currToken])
                    {
                        if (stringStack.top() != ")")
                        {
                            pnTokens.push_back(stringStack.top());
                            stringStack.pop();
                        }

                        if (stringStack.size() <= 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        if (stringStack.top() == ")")
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stringStack.push(currToken);
        }
        else if (currToken == "(")
        {
            if (stringStack.size() > 0)
            {
                while (stringStack.top() != ")")
                {
                    pnTokens.push_back(stringStack.top());
                    stringStack.pop();

                    if (stringStack.size() <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                stringStack.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    while (stringStack.size() > 0)
    {
        if (stringStack.top() != ")")
        {
            pnTokens.push_back(stringStack.top());
        }
        stringStack.pop();
    }

    std::reverse(pnTokens.begin(), pnTokens.end());

    //if it's gotten this far, the formula was valid
    //destroy the current tree to make room

    destroyTree();

    //parse polish notation into tree
    treeRoot = new TreeNode;
    currentNode = treeRoot;
    treeIsDone = false;

    for (stringVectorIterator = pnTokens.begin(); stringVectorIterator != pnTokens.end(); stringVectorIterator++)
    {
        currToken = *stringVectorIterator;
        if (precedence.find(currToken) != precedence.end())
        {
            //if the token is an operator
            currentNode->setOp(currToken);

            currentNode = insertNode(currentNode);
        }
        else
        {
            //if it's a number or a variable
            if (currentNode->first != NULL)
            {
                //if the current node has it's first branch initialized
                while (currentNode->last != NULL)
                {
                    //while the last branch is initialized
                    currentNode = currentNode->parent;
                }

                currentNode = insertNode(currentNode);
            }

            if (std::all_of(currToken.begin(), currToken.end(), ::isdigit))
            {
                //if it's a number
                currentNode->setVal((uint32_t)atoi(currToken.c_str()));
            }
            else
            {
                //if it's something else, a variable
                currentNode->setVar();
            }

            if (currentNode != treeRoot)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode->parent;
            }

            //since we just moved up, we know at least the first branch is used
            //so only check the last
            while (currentNode->last != NULL)
            {
                //if the last node is not free
                if (currentNode == treeRoot)
                {
                    //if we're at the root, and it's totally populated
                    treeIsDone = true;
                    break;
                }

                currentNode = currentNode->parent;
            }

            if (!treeIsDone)
            {

                currentNode = insertNode(currentNode);
            }
        }
    }
    return(true);
}

uint8_t ExpressionTree::evaluate(uint32_t tVal)
{
    return((uint8_t)treeRoot->evaluate(tVal));
}
```